# Adding link to `My Accounts` section in SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online

Is it possible to add one more link under below links in `My Accounts` in sharepoint online.

`My Profile`

`My Account`

`Sign out`

Or how can we make JS code to run on all pages?

Answer (score 1):

Not really. That's standard navigation across various Microsoft cloud services. You'd only be able to alter that with some client-side JavaScript and injecting elements directly with something like jQuery in between the desired elements. Things like that work, but can be unreliable as they depend on Microsoft not changing the name of an element you're looking for.

Comment: So where do I need to add the jquery code so that it effect globally everywhere?

Comment: The basic answer is on a master page that you call everywhere. You'd have to experiment with it because putting that sort of jQuery in that inserts your links into Microsoft's can be a bit wonky depending on what else is going on on the page. Search for the id of the element you want to precede it, insert your content after with jQuery and it should work. But that depends on load order, the page not taking too long to load and on Microsoft having an easy to find/unchanging ID/unique class for the element you want to put your content after. I'd advise against unless you have NO other options.